# Getting warning when compiling Lisp interperater in C

Tags: c

I keep getting a uses gets() warning when trying to compile my interperater and nothing is outputing in the terminal. I changed gets() to fgets() as well but still its not outputing anything and gives me an error:

```
$ ./littleLisp 
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
5.000000
littleLisp.c:16:18: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1
        while (fgets(str) && strcmp(str, "")) {
               ~~~~~    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:238:1: note: 'fgets' declared here
char    *fgets(char * __restrict, int, FILE *);
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [littleLisp] Error 1
$ make littleLisp
cc     littleLisp.c   -o littleLisp
littleLisp.c:16:18: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1
        while (fgets(str) && strcmp(str, "")) {
               ~~~~~    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:238:1: note: 'fgets' declared here
char    *fgets(char * __restrict, int, FILE *);
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [littleLisp] Error 1
```

Any idea whats going on?

Here is the gist:

https://gist.github.com/rahul1346/8596118b834ecf41b1d9

Comment: Which part of "too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 1" isn't clear?  The man page for fgets describes the arguments: `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) of `fgets()`, the syntax is

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

so, a call to `fgets()` needs to have three arguments.

In your code, `while (fgets(str).....`, it has only one.

Comment: Is there a need to use fgets()?

Comment: Yes, you _should_ use `fgets()`. Its safer than `gets()`.